# help needed to publish android app in market

Tags: android-maps

I have made a application in android with map view and I want to publish it on market.

So first of all how to export final APK from eclipse and second Google map API key for release

Please, help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For creating the apk file.

```
Right click on your project->Export

Select the Android->Export Android Application

then next

In this wizard by default you get your project name which you have selected then next

in this keystore you have to create your keystore as first time then select Create new keystore and set the path like this way or you can browse it by click on browse button
path e.g. D:\app\myapp\my_release.keystore

set the password here with confirm password then next.

Set the Alias name here
Set the password and confirm password (this is different from the previous one but)
Set the year and other details
then click next
here set the path for your apk file
for e.g. D:\app\myapp\my_app.apk
```

now your apk file was created but you have set the map api key with this newly created keystore for mobile device.

obtain your map key using this keystore like this way

```
c:\java\...\bin Keytool –list -alias youraliasname –keystore D:\app\myapp\my_release.keystore -storepass yourpassword -keypass youraliaspassword then enter
```

now sign up and obtain map key from google site with this certificate fingerprint and change the api key in your xml file (Note this api key will work only of the mobile as you generate for your emulator you have to also keep save as backup).

now again regenerate the apk file as above step. But this time you have to select existing keystore

Comment: @pratik...thanks for your help...but can u also help me how to upload app to market...i have gone through sites where it says i have to create an account on developer.Google.com and pay 25$...after that what is the next step?

Answer (score 1):

Release: right click on the project, go to the android tools, choose the option that reads something like "export signed package". For the key, sign up for one. It really boils down to that. But the complete manual/helps are online, and easy to find.

I wonder where you're stuck, but just read these topics:

[Signing Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html)
Versioning Your Applications
Preparing to Publish
Publishing on Android Market

(I've linked the first, the rest are on the left hand side of that first link).

For the google maps API you'll get far enough using [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html) link i presume