# MapView with release key shows only blank page

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I have a problem with MapView activity , i've used debug key and MapView worked perfectly but when i registered relese key MapView shows only blank page, any suggestions?

Comment: this [question][1] shows how to create release key for map (different than the application key)


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315635/help-needed-to-publish-android-app-in-market

Answer (score 2):

> When you run your app with release key map did not show because
>   release key is for releasing the app to android market &  your
>   android:debuggable="false" is set in manifest.xml.
>
> If you upload this build on android market & then install your app
>   from market the map wil appear.
>       Basically debug key is for debug mode in which android:debuggable="true"  & release key for release mode in which
>   android:debuggable="false" is set in manifest.xml.....

Answer (score 0):

@user1251397 -- 
      user1151208 -- is right but You can test app without uploading to the market too. Just install apk which you created to upload on market using Android Injector or by downloading through mail.