# Google map just shows grey grid and markers

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-manifest, android-mapview

Both in eclipse and when uploaded to Play Store the app just shows the grey grid and the custom markers I added but the actual map is not shown. 
I am using the keys from the previous developer before me and the previous versions seem to work on Google Play but when I build it it fails to show the map.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: the maps will eventually need an internet connection, do you have it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Maps API key is connected to they keystore, you should ask the previous developer for the keystore and export your APK with it. Otherwise, you follow the steps in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315635/help-needed-to-publish-android-app-in-market) and when you get the MD5 fingerprint you sign up [here](https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup) to get new Google Maps API key.

Answer (score 3):

Only two reasons this would ever happen:

1. Your device does not have an internet connection or is otherwise unable to download the map tiles because of a firewall on your network etc.
2. You are using an API key for the maps library that doesn't match the certificate you are signing the apk with. Remember that Eclipse signs the apk with a debug key, and you use a different key for publishing. See [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey) documentation for details on this.