# Java Android Google Map API sign up . MD5 certificate fingerprint and not SHA1

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

No map shows up but a grid. So I looked up some sample fixes and came to this

[help needed to publish android app in market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315635/help-needed-to-publish-android-app-in-market)

however, after running the cmds as suggested, I end up with a SHA1 certificate fingerprint. But when I go to sign up for a google API key, I see I need an MD5 certificate fingerprint instead. How do I tackle this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And here is the solution to your problem

1. Open Command Prompt and navigate to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin`(might be different in your case).
2. As you are following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315635/help-needed-to-publish-android-app-in-market) that means you have `keystore` with you.If yes move to step 3. else create a new `keystore` like mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315635/help-needed-to-publish-android-app-in-market).
3. Type the following command `keytool.exe -v -list -keystore " <path_of_keystore_youhave_created_in_step_2>"` it will ask for password use the same password you have used while creating `keystore` and you will get `SHA1` `MD5` and many information you have provided while creating `keystore`.

Answer (score 1):

First find the location of debug.keystore (In eclipse you can find location of debug.keystore at Window->Preference->Android->Build).Then navigate the path of `keytool.exe` in command prompt. `keytool.exe` is located inside  Java –> JDK – > bin folder inside  program files.
For window write the following code in command prompt `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin> keytool -list –alias androiddebugkey -keystore <path_of_debug.keystore> -storepass android -keypass android`

Here `<path_of_debug.keystore>` is path of debug.keystore. For my case it is C:\Users\virus.android.

Copy the MD5 key(eg:- BE:05:C8:F2:42:7A:97:37:78:EE:BD:4A:31:7D:A6:69) and goto on following link to find google map api key  http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html

Comment: This method doesn't work for later version. Goodle had change it later with google map api 3 (may be from)...