# Java Android Google Map. Only the grid shows up

Tags: java, android, google-maps

No map shows up but a grid. So I looked up some sample fixes and came to this

[help needed to publish android app in market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315635/help-needed-to-publish-android-app-in-market)

I followed the instruction, and completed the steps but my map is still not showing up. Any ideas what I may be missing here?

## UPDATE

I just recreated the key for the third time and I get the same problem. The error messages are as below.

```
08-12 00:16:51.081: W/PackageManager(52): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.cp in package com.android.providers.contacts    
08-12 00:16:52.281: E/EventHub(52): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
08-12 00:16:52.281: E/EventHub(52): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
08-12 00:16:52.951: E/System(52): Failure starting core service
08-12 00:16:52.951: E/System(52): java.lang.SecurityException
08-12 00:16:52.951: E/System(52):   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
08-12 00:16:52.951: E/System(52):   at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
08-12 00:16:52.951: E/System(52):   at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
08-12 00:16:52.951: E/System(52):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:176)
08-12 00:16:52.951: E/AndroidRuntime(52): Crash logging skipped, no checkin service
08-12 00:17:00.831: W/ActivityManager(52): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.ussd.IExtendedNetworkService }: not found
```

In manifest, I have these specified

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: What are the steps that you have taken? Are you loading the apk via debug?

Comment: the steps are at the link I posted above.

Answer (score 3):

Either:

- You do not have [a valid Maps API key that corresponds with the app signing key that you are using](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey), or
- You do not have the `INTERNET` permission, or
- You do not have an Internet connection

Comment: I generated the key I am using now with the MD5 certificate fingerprint I am using. I followed the direction as specified on the other page. I believe I do have INTERNET permission set in Android.manifest and I am online.

Comment: @Kobojunkie: All that I can tell you is that the three problems I list above are the known causes for the symptoms that you describe.

Comment: I have so far recreated the key twice following the same process.

Comment: @Kobojunkie: Here is a sample Maps app: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Maps/NooYawk Paste your API key into the layout file and try it. If the map works, then there is something wrong with your app (e.g., `<uses-permission>` elements in the wrong place). If the map does not work, then there is something wrong with your Maps API key.

Answer (score 0):

I you are running your application from eclipse onto an  emulator a a device connected via usb you have to use a maps key generated using the MD5 fingerprint of the **debug** key. If you are using your own key than you have to export the project, sign it with your key and than you will be able to see the map.

Answer (score 0):

I think You should use correct Api_key and the same package name which you got from google developer account of https://console.developers.google.com/project?pli=1